# removing pages that have been loaded in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a page where I load other pages inside a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".animalFinder", function()
    { 
    var $inputElement = $(this),
            inputName = $inputElement.attr("name");

    $("#freeload").show();
    $("#freeload").load("animaldetails.php?anmalid="+inputName);
    });
  });
```

The pages that it load in contain some information about the animal and a script that makes it alert the user what the animal noise is.

```
$(document).on("click", "input.noisebutton", function() {   
    var answer = confirm("Want to play noise?")
    if (answer){             
             var $inputElements = $(this),
            inputNames = $inputElements.attr("name");
        alert(inputNames);
    }
    else{
        return false;   
    }
});
```

The animals and their noises are added into name fields as they are loaded from the database, so I can create pages for different animals dynamically.

The problem is after I load the first animal page I have no method of deleting it, from the page, this would be fine, except that the script held in the animal details page is created again and when I click on the animal noise button for the next animal loaded into the div it runs the script twice as there are now two instances of it.

I would rather keep the script in the animal page as it is really lightweight and only used in that one instance, this makes the rest of it more efficient as the animal details page is not used often compared to the rest but I do need a method to remove either the scripts or the whole page when a new one is pressed.

Hope the question is clear

Comment: It seems that you have a general performance issue. Attaching all events to the document itself is usually not a good idea, you might want to be more specific and attach the events to sub-containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't the markup, but the fact that you're binding handlers to the `document` multiple times. Since you're using event delegation, you should be able to attach the handler once in the container page, and simply not rebind each time you load an animal page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".animalFinder", function () {
        var $inputElement = $(this),
            inputName = $inputElement.attr("name");

        $("#freeload").show();
        $("#freeload").load("animaldetails.php?anmalid=" + inputName);
    });

    $(document).on("click", "input.noisebutton", function () {
        var answer = confirm("Want to play noise?")
        if (answer) {
            var $inputElements = $(this),
                inputNames = $inputElements.attr("name");
            alert(inputNames);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I was trying to keep it out of the container page as it is already pretty bloated, is there no way to destroy it without having to move it? The main reason I'm loading it from another page is because it is a not an often used feature that I don't want to have to load every time.

Comment: The only option would be to bind directly to the element each time: `$(input.noisebutton).on('click', function() {...})` When the page is reloaded, the element is removed and so is the handler.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#freeload").empty()` should do the trick, but you'll need to check to see if you've already attached your event handler/executed your code. I would use a flag variable outside of your loaded code to indicate whether or not the script has already been executed once before, then check that variable before reattaching the handler. If you need the script to be executed, but the old handler detached, check the condition, then detach the handler and reattach your new one.

Another thing you might consider (if I'm reading your comment correctly) is to use the flag variable in your event handler to determine whether or not it should execute the code inside, a flag you set to `true` when you have a page loaded, and when you call `.empty()` set it back to `false`

Comment: I tried the .empty method and it seemed to have already smooshed all the code together so even when I emptied the contents of the div the jquery method was still running. It is now increasingly looking like I will have to offload the code somewhere else.

Comment: Oh, you want to unbind the event when you clear the page from the dom?